# How can i solve this error?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image: Error]

I have already tried to remove my old blender and download the latest version but it does not work.

Comment: It seems that a shininess value on a material from the model you try to import is set to a negative value. This is the cause of the error apparently. So if you can't change that before importing, I don't think there is a solution, except changing the code in the addon.

Comment: Try to change the line 1354 in the indicated file (the last of the list in the error report) from "ma_wrap.roughness = 1.0 - (sqrt(fbx_shininess) / 10.0)" to "ma_wrap.roughness = 1.0 - (sqrt(fbx_shininess) / 10.0) if fbx_shininess > 0 else 1" (keep the spaces at the begining of the line and make a copy of the file before changing it).